# Can someone come up with a better way to write $V = \operatorname{diag}(x_1,x_2)(Y-\mathbf{1}X^TY)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, soft-question, matrix-equations, article-writing

$\newcommand{\diag}{\operatorname{diag}}$Let $X = \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix}$, $Y= \begin{bmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \end{bmatrix}$

> I have a vector:
>
> $$V = \begin{bmatrix} x_1(y_1 - \sum\limits_{i \in \{1,2\}} x_iy_i)\\ x_2(y_2 -
> \sum\limits_{i \in \{1,2\}} x_iy_i)  \end{bmatrix}$$

I re-arranged the above to put into a matrix equation:

$$V= \diag(x_1,x_2)\Bigg(\begin{bmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x_1 & x_2 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \end{bmatrix}\Bigg)$$

where $\diag(x_1,x_2) = \begin{bmatrix} x_1 & 0 \\ 0 & x_2 \end{bmatrix}$

> Which I then write $V = \diag(x_1,x_2)(Y-\mathbf{1}X^TY)$

But unfortunately I think is confusing and not very visually pleasing. Is there some way to rewrite the expression of $V$ so that it is more compact. I am thinking some way to use Kronecker product, or something like that but I am not sure

Comment: @mvw: fixed, even uglier

Comment: what values does $i$ take? only 1 and 2?

Comment: @SiongthyeGoh Yess

Comment: $$V= \diag(x) (I_2 - 1_2 x^T) y$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your $V$ is
$$
V = 
\begin{pmatrix}
-x_1^2 y_1 - x_1 x_2 y_2 + x_1 y_1 \\
-x_2^2 y_2 - x_1 x_2 y_1 + x_2 y_2 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
thus a cubic polynomial for each component.